# Email encoding and basic auth in react

Tags: javascript, axios

My API looks something like this https://customerlink.org/api/data?email="

I have no problem using it with postman, I just need  to encode the query string(email), as ‘@’ is not a valid character.

I used a website to encode the email and it worked with no problem. I used Postman and add the Basic Auth credentials

however I am confused on how to add the email part and how to encode it from my react app.

```
var api_url = "https://customerlink.org/api/data?email="
var email = "testemail@gmail.com"
var username = 'username';
var password = 'password';
var basicAuth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);

axios.post(api_url + email, {}, {
headers: { 'Authorization': + basicAuth }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log('Authenticated');
}).catch(function(error) {
console.log('Error on Authentication');
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `encodeURI(uri)` if you need to, but the @ symbol can be used in a query string just fine.

```
let uri = "https://customerlink.org/api/data?email=my@email.com"
let encodedUri = encodeURI(uri);
```